# AccessViolationException on SByte[].Length

Tags: java, c#, arrays, access-violation

First of all, I took a look into other AccessViolationException problems here on SO, but mostly I didn't understand much because of terms like "marshalling" and unsafe code, etc.

Context: I try to port some of the Java Netty code to C#. Maybe I mixed up the two languages and don't see it anymore.

I just have two methods, one forwarding parameters to the other.

```
public override ByteBuf WriteBytes(sbyte[] src)
{
    WriteBytes(src, 0, src.Length);
    return this;
}

public override ByteBuf WriteBytes(sbyte[] src, int srcIndex, int length)
{
    SetBytes(WriterIndex, src, srcIndex, length); // AccessViolationException throws here
    return this;
}
```

Now, I'm testing the first method in my unit test, like this:

```
var byteArray = new sbyte[256];
for (int i = 0, b = sbyte.MinValue; b <= sbyte.MaxValue; i++, b++) // -128 ... 127
{
    byteArray[i] = (sbyte) b;
}

buffer.WriteBytes(byteArray); // this is the invokation
```

What I found so far is, that the problem seems to arise from the "length" parameter. I don't know, but maybe I'm not allowed to use "src.Length" in the first method to pass it to the second.
Also, please note that I am using sbyte, not byte. (I hope this doesn't matter.)

Does this have to do with pass-by-reference or pass-by-value of arrays?

**Edit:**
I found that the exception must be thrown anywhere in the depths of SetBytes. However, I believed that SetBytes never was called because I set a breakpoint on the method's entry. But the debugger never stopped there. I believe that the debugger doesn't work properly as it sometimes doesn't stop at the breakpoints I set. After I have managed to debug the whole depths of SetBytes, the AccessViolationException was never thrown. I then *RUN* the test 10x and the exception didn't appear. Then I *DEBUG*ged the whole thing again and the exception appeared again.

Why is that??

Comment: Everything working fine when I tried in C# console application. Are you sure you have mentioned everything?

Comment: Does it work if you change it to length -1? Wondering if SetBytes is using the length param as an ending index; in which case, being 0 based, the array length would be 1 too many.

Comment: @kapil Yes, I think I gave all necessary information. Maybe it's because of the unit test context?

Comment: @AllanElder Using length-1 works, probably because a new int parameter is created under the hood. However, passing length-1 is invalid for the SetBytes method. If I use new values for all parameters, like SetBytes(0, new sbyte[10], 0, 10), it works. When I start using the correct values again, it works for the first 3 parameters, but when passing the original "length", the exception is thrown.